# GeoGraphics not appearing in pdf if GeoMarker used in function

Tags: printing

Why does print to pdf work fine for

```
GeoGraphics[Here]
```

but only the GeoMarker shows up for

```
GeoGraphics[{
  Tooltip[GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{-37.831564, 144.8933549}]], 
   "ScienceMuseum"]
  }, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[8, "Kilometers"], ImageSize -> Full]
```

Note: i can get the GeoGraphic to print if I delete the GeoMarker, Tooltip and ImageSize.

```
GeoGraphics[{
  GeoPosition[{-37.831564, 144.8933549}]
  }, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[8, "Kilometers"]]
```

do I need to export it as it's own graphic and then import it back in as an image?